Should I use Overleaf or offline editors for writing a 110 page LaTeX document code?
I am converting some notes and some proofs of theorems in 7 research papers into LaTeX which were about 110 pages in word. I am also learning LaTeX from the textbook More Math into LaTeX by George Gratzer and I have some experience of using MathStackexchange. I bought paid plan of Overleaf for 1 month to typeset my notes but I also learnt later that many people use offline LaTeX packages for typing long documents like mine.
So, can you please let me know if I should use Overleaf or offline editors and why?
Thank you very much!

start with overleaf. switch to a local installation when you get sufficiently frustrated by the limitations to put in the extra effort required for a local setup. but do keep local backups.

you should use the tool that fits you best. If you like overleaf use it (but download your work regularly and compile locally sometimes too so that you have a backup if internet breaks), if you like to work locally do it (but backup e.g. on overleaf in case your PC breaks down.

I voted to close as opinion-based, but if you want my opinion: I think Overleaf is the best solution for collaborating with others on the same document, but when I am the only person writing a document then I much prefer using my offline setup (which is just a text editor with a built-in terminal) because it is faster, more flexible, easier to debug, easier to do file management, etc.

If the document is just math notes without many complicate drawings etc., then the free overleaf version should probably be able to compile 110 pages.

Edited
Personally, I have almost always coded in LaTeX locally and I don't find much use in Overleaf.
I use TexMaker, it's really not complicated to install and it works very well. This has the advantage of having access to your documents everywhere, including when you travel.
As for Overleaf, it seems to me that it is impossible to import .Tex or .bib files individually, you have to zip your files and then send them to OverLeaf. The only advantage of Overleaf is that it compiles in real time. But quite honestly, I largely do without it.
You even just told that Overleaf could be paid for, one more reason not to use it in my opinion, the advantage of latex is among others to be completely free
The only thing I paid for LaTeX was VerbTeX (it's 10€ if your interested), a LaTeX editor for Android phone that compiles online, yes, but is very convenient and automatically downloads the PDF after compilation (see pictures).




thanks for editing: I've cleaned up my comments.
